# Search string end part in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to find records that have the same final:

http://www.a.com/a.html_art123
http://www.b.com/b.html_art123

the final part "art123" is what differences the record.
i'm using split_part but the query is too slow.

is there another way to solve this ?

```
split_part('http://www.a.com/a.html_art124', '_', 2)
art124
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the LIKE operator in your query.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%art123'
```

The % matches any sequence of zero or more characters of that field.